# How to expand Static TreeView Item programmatically

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview, treeviewitem

I have a tree structure like the shown below, where I use `Customers` and `Departements` as Folders to group each type of treevew items. Company_A, Company_B,.. & Customer_1, Customer_2,... and Departement_1, Departement_2, ...are bound to to viewmodels: the point is when i make search for certain item i need to expand all the nodes containing it up to Company node, my problem is how to expand the static nodes (`Customers`, `Departements`).

Thanks in advance.

```
>Company_A
    >Customers
        -Customer_1
        _Customer_2
    >Deparatements
        -Departement_1
        -Departement_2
>Company_B
    >Customers
        -Customer_3
        -Customer_4
        -Customer_5
    >Deparatements
        -Departement_3
        -Departement_4
        -Departement_5
```

Comment: Maybe you need to property [`IsExpanded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.isexpanded.aspx)?

Comment: @ Anatoliy : i use IsExpanded in the viewmodels but for Customers and Departements they are not bound to viewmodels

Comment: treeview.Expand(treeViewItem);